# can't make an iframe content overlap neighboring div as per z index

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an iframe having a mouse over functionality showing an panel on mouse over ,I want to give that panel highest z-index as I want it to overlap over all other elements in the page

but I can't do this as the panel z:index is confided to the its page(iframe page) and not the parent page holding the iframe,so whenever it overflows when it touches the surrouding divs here is my HTML for that iframe:

```
<div class="center_content" style="width:60% z-index:100">


  <div class="mainBar" style="position:relative;top:30px;">
 <iframe src="calender.aspx" width="100%" height="100%"  frameborder="0"  >                                      </iframe>
   </div>
```

here are some screen shots for better understanding:
[image: without overflow]
[image: withoverflow]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot make the tooltip inside the `iframe` overlaps the iframe boundaries and make it visible also on its parent element

I think you need to check the position of that overlay and align it differently

Comment: so I am thinking of using ajax(although I am new to that too),but would it solve my problem I mean if I use ajax?

Comment: a solution that makes you avoid frame/iframe will let you position properly that popup via css